# Speed up iterating over Mongo cursor

Tags: python, mongodb

I have more data than I can load into memory, and I am trying to iterate over all the results of my cursor. The problem is that the further I iterate in the cursor, the slower the results become, until they slow to a crawl:

```
In: 
start = time.time()
db.collection.find({})[10]
end = time.time()

print (end - start)

Out:
0.107940673828125

In:
start = time.time()
db.collection.find({})[200000]
end = time.time()

print (end - start)

Out:
9.331923007965088
```

As this progresses further, it becomes even slower and more infeasible for my purposes. Is there a way to speed up the iteration without loading all the results into local memory?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question isn't really iterating over a cursor. Rather, it is opening multiple cursors and (re)reading more data with every pass. This is quite resource intensive and unlikely to be successful long term.

#### `.toArray()`

You have several options here. The first, if you want to continue with an approach closer to what you are currently doing, is to load all of the data into RAM *once* and then continuing referring back to that object. So rather than making multiple `.find({})` calls to the database, you save the results from a single call as an array. This is described [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#iterator-index) and would look something like this:

```
var myCursor = db.collection.find(  );
var documentArray = myCursor.toArray();
var myDocument = documentArray[10];
...
myDocument = documentArray[200000];
```

#### Iterate a Cursor

But assuming that you are indeed consuming all results in order, then I would not recommend the approach above. Rather you can actually just iterate a single cursor, which will stream the data back to the client in batches. This is described [earlier on the same page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#manually-iterate-the-cursor), and would look something like this:

```
var myCursor = db.users.find( );

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
}
```

#### Keyset Pagination

Finally, another approach is to use "keyset pagination". With this approach, each request to the database will pull the next set of results based on the maximum item retrieved previously. So your first request would look like this:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(10)
```

And all subsequent requests will look similar but also include a `$gt` filter based on the last document processed:

```
db.collection.find({_id:{$gt: <_id of last document processed>}}).sort({_id:1}).limit(10)
```

Each of these retrievals will be efficient as they can use the `_id` index to process and return only the documents related to the current batch as opposed to reprocessing more data each time.